# Hide x-axis label in chartsjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm working with chartjs, but I'm stumbling upon the problem that there is no option to hide the X-axis labels, while the tags upon hover should still display. I have tried various solutions here on stackoverflow, but to no avail.

I am using the latest chart.js file, as found on their github: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js

Here is a bit of my javascript code which is used to generate the graphs.

```
var canvasWeek = {
        labels : <?=json_encode($dateArrayWeek);?>,
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor : "#3685C6",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "#3079AA",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#e47b25",
                pointHighlightStroke : "#FFF",
                data : <?=json_encode($brutoValWeek);?>
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor : "#3C897A",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor : "#3C897A",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#e47b25",
                pointHighlightStroke : "#FFF",
                data : <?=json_encode($nettoValWeek);?>
            }
        ]

    }

window.onload = function(){
    var ctxW = document.getElementById("canvas-week").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctxW).Line(canvasWeek, {
        responsive: true
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just replace Bar with Line in the linked duplicate. Cheers!

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. Could you give an example with the above-mentioned code? P.S: I can show my trial-code in an hour.

Comment: That's strange - it seems to be working for me (see http://jsfiddle.net/vxjnncxt/). Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Made a typo, now it works! I'll flag it as a resolved duplicate.